# display members list using zoo visitor default members group

Tags: members, devdemon, zoo-visitor

I am trying to display a members list using zoo visitor.

I cannot display the default members group.  It only displays new custome members group I have created.  How can I get this members list to display the default members group #5

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:members group_id="5"}
{visitor:member_lastname} {visitor:member_firstname} 
{/exp:zoo_visitor:members}

{exp:zoo_visitor:memberlist group_id="5"
{title} {visitor:member_lastname} {visitor:member_firstname} 
{/exp:zoo_visitor:memberlist}
```

Comment: Isn't the parameter "member_group" instead of "group_id"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try below code for member list.

```
{!-- Limit as per your scenario --}
{exp:visitor:members member_group="5" limit="800"}
    {visitor:member_firstname} {visitor:member_lastname}
{/exp:visitor:members}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Romans-8---31-39

Although I am not sure about the Zoo Visitor parameter but I am looking at Visitor documentation (EE3) and the parameter is **member_group** not group_id. Why not try it?

{exp:zoo_visitor:memberlist member_group="5"}
{title} {visitor:member_lastname} {visitor:member_firstname} 
{/exp:zoo_visitor:memberlist}

Comment: I tried this.  I have over 700 members in group #5, this code only displays 4 members.